# TypeError: d3.forceSimulation().size is not a function (d3 v4)

Tags: d3.js

I'm just starting with d3.js and have copied the example for d3.js v3 and trying to adapt it for v4. I have the following part of code:

```
var width = 960,
  height = 500,
  fill = d3.schemeCategory20;

// another code

var force = d3.forceSimulation()
  .size([width, height]) // the error occurred at this row 
  .nodes([{}])
  .linkDistance(50)
  .charge(-200)
  .on("tick", tick);
```

`d3.forceSimulation()` is an operator of v4, so my question is: "How should I use all of the following operators with new `d3.forceSimulation()` syntax of version 4 of d3.js"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because `size()` is not a [simulation object method](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#user-content-api-reference)
see [the docs](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md) for more info

Comment: Looks like it's true. But can you suggest a newbie, where should i use `.size`, `.nodes` and other operators in v4?

Comment: There is many cases for each ,but the documentation is your friend, use the links above, and CTRL+F and you'll find what is available on each API.

Comment: But `.size` was a method in v3.  The docs are not very helpful in upgrading the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/issues/54), you can try to use the forceX/Y forces as below:

```
var force = d3.forceSimulation()
  .size([width, height]) // the error occurred at this row 
  .nodes([{}])
  .linkDistance(50)
  .charge(-200)
  .force("x", d3.forceX([width/2]).strength(0.01))
  .force("y", d3.forceY([height/2]).strength(0.01))
  .on("tick", tick);
```

You can play with the strength parameter to control how much spread out your graph is.